# The service is not responding to the control function. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, background-service

I created BackgroundService in .net core by extension AddHostedService<>().

It worked on old server but in new or local computer I am getting an error when try to run cmd command **net start ShopifyCloudSyncService**

*The service is not responding to the control function.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.*

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Either the service is not running (got an exception) and you need to check the event viewer on server for errors.  Or the service is running with different credential on new server than old server.  Background services run by default with a Service Account with no credentials.  If you are reading the environmental variables (including path) you will fail.

Comment: @jdweng But locally I have the same problem as on remote server. I don't think that reason is in Service Account. In EventView no any errors too

Comment: Can you run normally without service?  Do you have any log files that give any errors?  Can you debug in VS?